# Running a script on Outlook as a Word Highlighter

Tags: vba, outlook

Aim is to run a script on Outlook only when a specific rule is met, e.g. when the word "the" appears, a script will be run on that email which highlights all occurrences of the word "the". Have been attempting the code but do not know where I am going wrong. The code appears to be ready to use but when applied the word specified is not highlighted. A rule identifies a specific word e.g. "the" and then the script will highlight this word where applicable in the email identified. The script ideally only activates when a rule identifies this specified word. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
Sub Highlight_AllOccurencesOfSpecificWords(MyMail As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim strWord As String
    Dim strHTMLBody As String
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim moveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem


    strHTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'Change the word as per your wishes
    strWord = "the"
    If InStr(strHTMLBody, strWord) > 0 Then
    strHTMLBody = Replace(strHTMLBody, strWord, "<font style=" & Chr(34) & "background-color: yellow" & Chr(34) & ">" & strWord & "</font>")
    objMail.HTMLBody = strHTMLBody
    End If

    objMail.Save

End Sub 

Updated Code:
Option Compare Text
Sub Highlight_AllOccurencesOfSpecificWords(MyMail As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim strWord As String
    Dim strHTMLBody As String
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim moveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    strHTMLBody = MyMail.HTMLBody
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Words can be added/removed below in the brackets after Array in (" "), words can be typed within quotation marks
 myArray = Array("today", "tomorrow")

For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    If InStr(strHTMLBody, myArray(x)) > 0 Then
    strHTMLBody = Replace(strHTMLBody, myArray(x), "<font style=" & Chr(34) & "background-color: turquoise" & Chr(34) & ">" & myArray(x) & "</font>")
    MyMail.HTMLBody = strHTMLBody
    End If
Next x
    MyMail.Save


End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain what is going wrong.  Does this code give an error?  Does the code appear to work but "the" is not highlighted?  Something else?

Comment: The code does not give an error. The code appears to be fine but when testing it "the" is not highlighted.

Comment: @TonyDallimore the code works great on non-categorized mails. However, the highlighter does not work when there are categorisation rules in the mail. Even though the script rule is on top of the Rules and Alerts function. Could additions be made to the code to make sure the script runs first regardless and then the categorisation rules?

Comment: One of the options on the "Step1: Select action(s)" window of the Rules wizard is "Stop processing more rules".  This is the only way I know of limiting the number of rules against which a message is checked.  Could you have this option checked on some of your rules?

Comment: Yes that's possible. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The code was working well until yesterday as Outlook has slowed down with emails slow to load. Could it be possible that the code is causing Outlook to slow down @TonyDallimore? In order to allow the code to work Notifications for all macros has been enabled so when Outlook is opened up after closing, a notification comes up to enables/disable macros on ThisOutlook Session. A rule was set up to run the code when specific words where in the subject or body.

Comment: The updated (current code) has been added above to the original question.

Comment: I would expect this routine to be slow if it has to process many emails and if it finds many words to highlight. Every time you replace a word with a highlighted word, the VBA interpreter has to find a new block of memory to hold the longer string, move the amended string into that block and release the old block for garbage collection. Every time, the interpreter runs out of free memory, it calls the garbage collector to rearrange its memory so all the released memory is together and available for allocation. Most Html bodies are large so the garbage collector could be called frequently.

Comment: Since you say the routine has slowed, VBA garbage collection may not be the problem. I suspect a similar issue is occurring with the Outlook store. I do not know how Outlook manages its stores or its memory, but every time you save an amended body, it must face the same problem as the VBA interpreter. Since, Outlook has a Compact routine to be called by the user, I suspect, Outlook does not garbage collect until told to do so by the user. ...

Comment: Each run of the macro will have a different number of emails of differing complexity to process so it will be difficult to be sure if it has had an effect but I would try compacting the store holding these emails.

Comment: I have not timed these two approaches so I cannot be sure if my suggestion will speed things up but it believe it would.  You are looping looking for “today”.  For each “today” found, your code builds a new string.  A better approach might be to `Split` the original body by “today” and then `Join` the parts with the “highlighted today”.  This removes the loop and makes the interpreter do most of the work which should save a lot of temporary strings.  I suggest you create a test routine to time these two approaches.

Comment: The Outlook seemed to slow down after the weekend and as you were saying it could be slow if it has to process many emails. It seemed to slow down when the enable macros was selected to run the highlighter when the Outlook was opened after the weekend. I think it may be due to backlog of emails to be processed by highlighter code. Would this be plausible? I will try the Split and Join functions. I am not sure how those functions work. Do I insert; Dim Array as string and x=split("today", "tomorrow") before For x part of code and then after Next x, put x =Join("today, "tomorrow")?

Comment: Having more emails to process on a Monday seems a very plausible reasons for Outlook to open more slowly.  I have had a better look at your code and I no longer think using Split and Join would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your macro does nothing because the parameter is `MyMail` but the macro amends the body of `objItem`.

Delete `Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem`

Replace `objItem` by `MyMail` in:

```
strHTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody
objMail.HTMLBody = strHTMLBody
objMail.Save
```

I assume you have no `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.  This is good practice because it makes this type of error more difficult to commit.  I get a compile time error with your code.

I assume "the" is an substitute for the real word you wish to highlight. If the real word is obscure then there should be no problem.  However, if the string "the" is part of a URL or similar, this code will mess up the email.

I did not use a rule to test your code.  I selected an old email I was happy to corrupt and ran this code:

```
Sub TestHighlight()

  Dim Exp As Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select one or more emails then try again", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      Call Highlight_AllOccurencesOfSpecificWords(ItemCrnt)
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```

I recommend this technique which I use to test almost all my Outlook macros.